# Calculating total Amount of Internet Sales (AdventureWorks data) MDX

Tags: mdx, olap, adventureworks

How can I count the total number of sales in the "FactInternetSales" table for the selected member of the DATES hierarchy?

```
(
[Order Date].[DATES].CURRENTMEMBER, 
COUNT(DISTINCT([Fact Internet Sales].[Sales Order Number].[Sales Order Number]
)
```

this is what I have at the moment however it doesn't work :/

Comment: Are you using Adventure Works Cube? Or just the data out of Adventure Works DW?

Comment: Adventure works cube I made using AdventureWorksDW2012

Comment: Where can I find this fact table "FactInternetSales" it is a physical table in AdventureWorks or is created on processing a cube? If so how can I create it?

Comment: Ok I found that is included on AdventureWorks DW edition and not on AdventureWorks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try count on the outside with extra braces to indicate a set of tuples:

```
COUNT(
  {  
    [Order Date].[DATES].CURRENTMEMBER
    *
    [Fact Internet Sales].[Sales Order Number].[Sales Order Number]
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with set abc as
EXISTS([Fact Internet Sales].[Sales Order Number].[Sales Order Number], 
[Order Date].[DATES].CURRENTMEMBER,
"Fact Internet Sales"
)

member [Measures].[Count]
AS Count(Distinct(abc))

SELECT  [Measures].[Count] on 0
from [YourCube]
WHERE Order Date].[DATES].&[01/01/2015] --Some random value for slicer
```